# Create a Titleless/Borderless draggable wxFrame in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, events, wxwidgets, draggable

Hi i am trying to create a wxApp that will have not have a titlebar(including the minimize, maximize and close) icons that are by default provided. The code that i have is as follows:
**main.h**

```
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
  public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{

    MyFrame *prop = new MyFrame(wxT("MyFrame"));
    prop->Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

**myframe.h**

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
  MyFrame(const wxString& title);
  
  void OnClick(wxMouseEvent& event);

};
```

**myframe.cpp**

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 130))
{
  MyPanel *panel = new MyPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
  panel->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255,255,255));
  MyButton *button = new MyButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Ok"));

  Connect( wxEVT_LEFT_UP, 
      wxMouseEventHandler(MyFrame::OnClick));

  panel->Centre();
}


void MyFrame::OnClick(wxMouseEvent& event) 
{
  std::cout << "event reached frame class" << std::endl;
  
}
```

**mypanel.h**

```
class MyPanel : public wxPanel
{
public: 
  MyPanel(wxFrame *frame, int id);

  void OnClick(wxMouseEvent& event);
};
```

**mypanel.cpp**

```
MyPanel::MyPanel(wxFrame *frame, int id)
    : wxPanel(frame, id)
{
  Connect( wxEVT_LEFT_UP, 
      wxMouseEventHandler(MyPanel::OnClick));
} 

void MyPanel::OnClick(wxMouseEvent& event) 
{
  std::cout << "event reached panel class" << std::endl;
  
}
```

**mybutton.h**

```
class MyButton : public wxPanel
{
public:
  MyButton(wxPanel *panel, int id, const wxString &label);

  void OnClick(wxMouseEvent& event);

};
```

**mybutton.cpp**

```
void MyButton::onClick(wxMouseEvent &event)
{

}
```

What i want is:

1. There should be no title bar(including the 3 maximize, minimize & close buttons) at the top.
2. Now since there is no titlebar at the top of the frame, there is no way to drag or close or maximize or minimize the window. For that i want to create a custom titlebar at the top which should have the three customized maximized,minimized and close button and also i should be able to drag the frame by double clicking and holding and dragging the topmost part of the newly created frame.

Is this possible in wxWidgets? If yes, how can i achieve this?

I am not proposing any new way of dragging. The new frame/window that we will have should also be dragged only by its own customized title bar. It's exactly like dragging the old frame by double clicking and dragging the frame in the native case. I just want to customize the native title bar. Like increase its height, change it's colour, change how to three buttons(minimize, maximize and close) look.

Comment: don't create a TLW as wxFrame. Make it as wxPanel. This way you will not have a title bar. Then create you own title bar at the top and handle mouse events yourself. Just keep in mind - title bar is not only for displaying the title and moving the window. It allows a window border/decorations and window resizing. So you will have to do a lot of custom work.

Comment: Also, I think since you want such a customization level - you chose a wrong toolkit - wxWidgets uses native set of windows/widgets/controls whenever possible. You should look into Qt as they are doing custom painting and will allow you to do anything you want with the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the simplest example I can think of how to create a frame with a pseudo titlebar that can be clicked to drag the frame around.  This example shows which mouse events need to be handled to drag the window around and how to do the calculations needed in those event handlers.

Note that moving the frame needs to be done in screen coordinates, but the coordinates received in the event handlers will be in client coordinates for the title bar.  This example also shows how to do those coordinate conversions.

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

class CustomTitleBar:public wxWindow
{
public:
    CustomTitleBar(wxWindow* p) : wxWindow(p,wxID_ANY)
    {
        m_dragging = false;

        SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
        Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,&CustomTitleBar::OnMouseLeftDown,this);
        Bind(wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST, &CustomTitleBar::OnMouseCaptureLost,
             this);
    }

    wxSize DoGetBestClientSize() const override
    {
        return wxSize(-1,20);
    }

private:
    void OnMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
    {
        if ( !m_dragging )
        {
            Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&CustomTitleBar::OnMouseLeftUp,this);
            Bind(wxEVT_MOTION,&CustomTitleBar::OnMouseMotion,this);
            m_dragging = true;

            wxPoint clientStart = event.GetPosition();
            m_dragStartMouse = ClientToScreen(clientStart);
            m_dragStartWindow = GetParent()->GetPosition();
            CaptureMouse();
        }
    }

    void OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&)
    {
        FinishDrag();
    }

    void OnMouseMotion(wxMouseEvent& event)
    {
        wxPoint curClientPsn = event.GetPosition();
        wxPoint curScreenPsn = ClientToScreen(curClientPsn);
        wxPoint movementVector = curScreenPsn - m_dragStartMouse;

        GetParent()->SetPosition(m_dragStartWindow + movementVector);
    }

    void OnMouseCaptureLost(wxMouseCaptureLostEvent&)
    {
        FinishDrag();
    }

    void FinishDrag()
    {
        if ( m_dragging )
        {
            Unbind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&CustomTitleBar::OnMouseLeftUp,this);
            Unbind(wxEVT_MOTION,&CustomTitleBar::OnMouseMotion,this);
            m_dragging = false;
        }

        if ( HasCapture() )
        {
            ReleaseMouse();
        }
    }

    wxPoint m_dragStartMouse;
    wxPoint m_dragStartWindow;
    bool m_dragging;
};

class Customframe : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Customframe(wxWindow* p)
        :wxFrame(p, wxID_ANY, wxString(), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(150,100),
                 wxBORDER_NONE)
    {
        CustomTitleBar* t = new CustomTitleBar(this);
        SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLUE);
        wxBoxSizer* szr = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        szr->Add(t,wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
        SetSizer(szr);
        Layout();
    }
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame():wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Custom frame Demo", wxDefaultPosition,
             wxSize(400, 300))
     {
         wxPanel* bg = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
         wxButton* btn = new wxButton(bg, wxID_ANY, "Custom frame");
         wxBoxSizer* szr = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
         szr->Add(btn,wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxALL));
         bg->SetSizer(szr);

         Layout();

         btn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::OnButton, this);
         m_customFrame = NULL;
     }
private:
    void OnButton(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
        if ( m_customFrame )
        {
            m_customFrame->Close();
            m_customFrame = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            m_customFrame = new Customframe(this);
            m_customFrame->CenterOnParent();
            m_customFrame->Show();
        }
    }

    wxFrame* m_customFrame;
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit()
        {
            MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

On windows, it looks like this.

[image: A custom frame with a custom title bar]

You should be able to add whatever buttons you want to the custom title bar exactly as you would add buttons to any other window.

Comment: Is it possible to make the wxFrame resizable using its borders but still not have the top border. For example, i tried the style `wxRESIZE_BORDER` and this is what i want but without the top border showing up. Is this possible? Also, when the user right clicks on the green titlebar in your demo, the  same menu options should open up as would when we right click on the native top border. For example, in case of ubuntu when the user right clicks on the green titlebar one of the menu options should be "Always on top".

Comment: If you want to allow the window to be resized without using the system resize border, you'll have to add a "resizing mode" similar to the dragging mode in the example above and have code for entering that mode and handling mouse events when in that mode.

Comment: For the system menu, I don't think there is a way to get it in wxWidgets, so platform specific code will be needed.  In MSW, you would use [GetSystemMenu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu) and on GTK you would use [gtk_application_get_app_menu](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#gtk-application-get-app-menu).  You can either convert the objects returned by those functions to a wxMenu and call `PopupMenu` or use platform specific code for the popup menu.  MacOS has its own way of doing menus so nothing is needed there.

Comment: Note: upon further investigation, the method `wxTopLevelWindow::MSWGetSystemMenu` does exist to get the menu on MSW.  I do not see a corresponding method for GTK, so I guess platform specific code is still needed there.

Answer (score 0):

"*Is this possible in wxWidgets?*"

Yes. You need to use a [wxWindow](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html) instead of a wxFrame and set some style for it. like `wxBORDER_NONE`. But you will have to implement many things that wxFrame already provides.

And your proposed way of dragging seems wrong/confusing to me. 99.99% of users prefer a UI they are used to it, avoiding to learn a new way of doing simple things they already know.

If you just want to avoid resizing then you have two ways:

- a) Catch the size-event and do nothing. Calling `event.Skip(false)`
  (to prevent handling in parent) is not neccessary.
- b) Once you have created your window and correctly sized, get its size and set it as max and min.

In both cases the user will see a "resize" mouse pointer when hovering the mouse at any border, but nothing else, no resizing, will be done.

Comment: @Rip2, he just `doesn't like the way it shows the title bar` ;-) Just like he doesn't like the native button L&F and prefer the panel instead.

Comment: @Ripi2 I am not proposing any new way of dragging. The new frame/window that we will have should also be dragged only by its own customized title bar. It's exactly like dragging the old frame by double clicking and dragging the frame in the native case. I just want to customize the native title bar(lookwise). Like increase its width, change it's colour, change how to three buttons(minimize, maximize and close) look.

Comment: @JasonLiam, you can drag the window by double clicking on the title bar. Only when I click and hold the title bar and then start dragging the window becomes draggable. Double click on the title bar do nothing!! Please re-read your OP - this is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Also, as I said above - wxWidgets uses native set of widgets, which means `native L&F` wherever possible. Make sure that this is exactly what you want, especially since this is your second question in this area. It is called `skinning` and wxWidgets is not designed for that. Qt is.

Comment: I don't know if you're are familiar with laptops. But in laptops, we drag a frame/window by double clicking on the title bar and then holding and dragging it here and there on the visible screen. That is the default behavior. This is using a trackpad that is attached with the laptop itself and you don't have a separate mouse. But if you have a separate mouse then there is no need to double click on the title tile bar using that separate mousr cursor. You can just single click and drag the frame by its titlebar. This(single click and drag) can also be done using the trackpad of laptop ofcourse.

Comment: @jasonliam, I work with many laptops and many different OSes. But I never heard about this double-click behavior. In fact I tried it (RHEL 7) and double clicking the title bar didn't do anything. I have default WM (GNOME).  But as New Pagodi did your job for you i won't comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

@JasonLiam,

Don't forget to place the application icon in the top left corner of you title bar and handle the right/left mouse clicks appropriately (as in native application) (if you want to go this route and get rid of the native frame window).

Thank you.