# Extracting control buttons from .msstyle

Tags: python, c++, windows, winapi, msstyles

Windows created by Windows have so-called control buttons. These buttons mean "minimize", "maximize", "restore", "close". These buttons can be found in .msstyle files under the path `DWMWindow > Common Properties`.

[image: MSStyle Editor]

The current .msstyle file can be found by using the registry editor at the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager` and accessing the DllName value.

[image: Regedit]

In C++, you can open a .msstyle file like this (Taken from [How to create control buttons exactly like Window's (OS) control buttons in wxWidgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524059/how-to-create-control-buttons-exactly-like-windows-os-control-buttons-in-wxwi)):

```
HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryEx(L"C:\\Windows\\Resources\\Themes\\aero\\aero.msstyles",
                                     0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(this->GetHandle()),L"DWMWindow");
```

Is it possible to "pull" icons from a given file, but using the python programming language?

I will be glad to any answer!

Answer (score 1):

For the given question, you could look into the [PyWin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) library

The library seems to contain within it an [OpenThemeData function](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/src/_winxptheme.i#L152)

The library also seems to contain a [LoadLibraryEx](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/win32evtlogutil.py#L167) function

The usage of a different example is [here as well](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/win32evtlogutil.py#L167)

```py
dllHandle = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(
    dllName, 0, win32con.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE
)
try:
    data = win32api.FormatMessageW(
        win32con.FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
        dllHandle,
        eventLogRecord.EventID,
        langid,
        eventLogRecord.StringInserts,
    )
finally:
    win32api.FreeLibrary(dllHandle)
```

It also seems to support the popular [winxptheme](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/winxptheme.py#L2) library

[Code inspired from](https://github.com/bramd/nvda-misc-deps/blob/3707b8e4052670c454343e32d8de3f0b8beab642/python/wx/lib/agw/aui/dockart.py#L941)

```py
        # Get the size of a small close button (themed)
hwnd = self.win.GetHandle()
theme1 = winxptheme.OpenThemeData(hwnd, "Window")
```

Based on both of these, I think the work to combine both should be relatively easy

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I would like to have a more complete idea of how to take an image out of a theme. It’s also not entirely clear how uxtheme.GetThemeStream works, which is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524059/how-to-create-control-buttons-exactly-like-windows-os-control-buttons-in- wxwi

Comment: @OKwy while Windows UI based API is not my strong suite, check out https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/832f17260fc53f4fd01d712f8f9ad0db2328356a/wx/lib/agw/aui/dockart.py#L1074 if this helps

Comment: Having scoured the Internet, I realized that msstyles is a regular dll file containing the necessary images. But the problem is that I didn’t find a good script for extracting images from the library. Maybe you have an idea how to extract these images?